# Python Kivy: unable to import main main

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, kivy

While reading the book, Creating Kivy apps with Python, it says to

```
"Next, update the imports in weather.kv to import this main module instead of the
 ListItemButton class; see Example 3-7.
 Example 3-7. Importing a custom class from main
 #: import main main
 #: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter"
```

which is supposed to be put in the .kv file for running.  However, I get the following error:

```
   File "/home/peter-brown/kivytest.py", line 58, in <module>
     DownloadApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 797, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 594, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1749, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1796, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1185, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1284, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1250, in execute_directives
     mod = __import__('.'.join(package.split('.')[:-1]))
 ValueError: Empty module name
```

TLDR: I'm getting an error that says the main.py file is an emtpy module.
It seems to just be the 'main' file because taking it out causes the app to run smoothly.

Can someone explain why this is so? And what I can do to fix it?

Comment: how are your files named?

Comment: Try without the space between `#:` and `import`.

Comment: @goCards, my .py file is named Download.py and the .kv file is named download.kv. Is it a file name thing? I thought the 'main' file was part of kivy.

Comment: No, you must have a module named main for that to work.

Comment: If your main file is called Download.py, they you use:

#:import main Download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the  [Kv Language docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#special-syntaxes). That import is asking kivy to import the module main as main. If there is no module main, then kivy will raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problem with that when I was doing example from his 4th kivy tutorial, because I used a different name.

So, in your case, if your file is Download.py, the line should be:

```
#:import main Download
```

Comment: I have found this same issue(my own fault) while working thorugh this book. Thank you for the answer.